# Windows 7 PC crashes on connecting dial-up modem

Tags: windows, bsod, modem, dial-up

I have a PC running Windows 7, and I'm using a USB external dial-up modem to connect to the Internet. 
However, once I plug in the modem, Windows displays a blue screen not unlike the one displayed by Windows Vista which contains text like `dump physical memory`.  Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you turn off the computer, plug in the modem and then boot up?  Also, what is the stop error you get?

Comment: what model modem?  Did you verify it is Win7 compatible and load the drivers before pluggin the modem in?

Comment: Post your blue screen of death info. It should give you the image name of the faulting kernel-space module. Also "Windows 7" and "Dialup Internet" are kind of oxymorons. I mean seriously, you're using Windows 7 to "dial up" to the internet??

Comment: Honestly, I do fall back to a hardware-based USB dial-up modem when a high-speed connection is not available. :P

Comment: You can use http://www.mydigitallife.info/bluescreenview-view-blue-screen-crash-information/ to get info from previous blue screen crashes.

Answer (score 1):

There is lot of what is wrong.

- Driver for USB (try latest from manufacturer of your motherboard)
- HW problem with USB (try connect another device to same USB port)
- Driver for that modem (try lates from USB modem manufacturer)
- HW problem with modem